# Edit a submit btn for nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I would like to customize the submit file btn. To do that, I'm using a pure css trick. But the problem is that this is not working as well than before the editing. I'm using cocoon to add images to my instance as a nested file.

I'm changing this (works perfectly) :

```
<div class="nested-fields col m4 s6">
    <div class="flat_photo_box">
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Into this (partially works):

```
<div class="nested-fields col m4 s6">
    <div class="image-upload">
       <label for="file-input<%=f.object.id%>">
         <span class="fa fa-download trash_nested_form"></span>
       </label>
       <%= f.file_field :image, id:"file-input#{f.object.id}" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this css trick :

```
.image-upload > input
{
   display: none;
}
.image-upload > label{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

ERROR = I can create as much nested form than I want, but paperclip only save the last image that I upload into the first nested element. Do you have an idea of where the mistake might come from

Answer (score 0):

You assign an `id` to the file_field, a html-id is supposed to be unique. While the page will render correctly, upon form submit only one will be submitted to the server. Instead write your field like this:

```
<%= f.file_field :image, class:"file-input#{f.object.id}" %>
```

Why do you want to assign a specific id?